# how to display database into combobox

Tags: vb.net

im getting error in combobox, instead the combobox display the database... it shows combobox.text = "System.Data.DataRowView" inside.

```
Private Sub FillCombo()
Try
    conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
    Dim sSQL As String = ("SELECT subject FROM student order by subject")
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sSQL, conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds)
    cmbsection.ValueMember = "ItemName"
    cmbsection.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    cmbsection.SelectedIndex = 0
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("ERROR : " & ex.Message.ToString)
End Try
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a simple case of setting the Datasource before the Valuemember.

```
cmbsection.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
cmbsection.ValueMember = "ItemName"
```

Comment: ops that was reaally missed program. i coded too long that makes me really confused and missed a simple problem :)

by the way can i ask how can i filter my combobox display, where SUBJECT consist of 2 which is "COE and IT" if im a COE, it should only display all COE and will not display IT.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub FillCombo()
Try
   conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
   Dim sSQL As String = ("SELECT subject FROM student order by subject")
   Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sSQL, conn)
   Dim ds As New DataSet
   da.Fill(ds)
   cmbsection.ValueMember = "ItemName"
   cmbsection.DataSource = ds;
   cmbsection.SelectedIndex = 0;
Catch ex As Exception
   MsgBox("ERROR : " & ex.Message.ToString)
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub FillCombo()
Try
    conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
    Dim sSQL As String = ("SELECT subject FROM student order by subject")
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sSQL, conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds)
cmbsection.Items.clear
For i as Integer = 0 to ds.Tables(0).rows.count-1
    cmbsection.Items.add( ds.Tables(0).rows(i).item("subject").tostring)

next

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("ERROR : " & ex.Message.ToString)
End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the

```
cmbsection.DisplayMember = "Subject"
cmbsection.ValueMember = "Subject"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub LoadProvince()
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection("server=.\LENOVO;uid=sa;pwd=123;database=SchoolDb;")
    cn.Open()

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Product;", cn)
    Dim dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt.Load(dr)
    dr.Close()

    cboPROVINCE.DisplayMember = "Product_NAME"
    cboPROVINCE.ValueMember = "Product_Id"
    cboPROVINCE.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```